# Converting hard-copy forms to electronic forms or a database

Tags: javascript, database, ms-access

I have about 5,000 hard copy forms that i need to be converted to electronic or created into a database such as microsoft access.

The goal is to avoid trying to manually put in each one of the 5,000 forms. This would be too tedious and take too much time.

I've been brainstorming for the longest, and have only come up with scanning them in. This would also be tedious and take a while. It seems to be no way around this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you mean [*forms*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/form#Noun), not [*forums*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forum#Noun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a scanner with a [document feeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_document_feeder).  You can stick stacks of paper in at a time, and it will pull each page through individually.

Something like Acrobat can handle the scanning/saving, and will even do OCR.

Answer (score 1):

Use form processing software (google: form ocr). If you dont want to scan them in I'm sure your local copy-shop will do that for your.
In google you will also find contractors that do the whole job.

Your options depend upon how many times you face this problem and how much you are willing to pay/do yourself